# Bypass Excel file selection confirmation for data connection with non-.txt text file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba, import

I have an Excel workbook that processes model output from another program.  That program produces space-delimited plain-text output files with a *".plt"* extension.  I have a data connection in Excel to bring those data in, but it requires more clicks than I would like.  Currently the work flow is this:

1. Run other model.
2. In Excel, click Data->Refresh All
3. In the file dialog box that opens, click on *"Text Files (*.prn, *.txt, *.csv)"*
4. Pull Down appears - click on : *"All Files (*.*)"*.
5. Select file name from list (filename never changes - Always *"Output.plt"*)
6. Select *"Import."*

From here, it remembers all of the settings for the data connection - locations, text to columns, etc.  Since my file name never changes, though, I wish it would remember the name of my file, so I would only have one or two clicks, instead of 5.

I tried to record a macro, going through all these steps, but the only piece that showed up in VBA is `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll`

Comment: How about 

Workbooks.Open Filename:= _ "C:\Desktop/Output.plt"

in a macro.

Comment: That opens Output.plt as a file, but it doesn't bring it in to my _ResultsAnalysisTemplate.xlsb_  I guess I could use VBA to open the file up, select each data group I need, and copy each to its appropriate place in the template, but I would've thought there would be a more direct solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an option to prompt for filename.

Go to Data / Connections, choose your connection, click properties.

Under the refresh control section, on the Usage tab, take the tick out of the box "prompt for file name on refresh"

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim File_Path As String
File_path=" C:\Users\owner\John\Output.plt"
Open File_Path for Input as #1
row_num= 5
Do until EOF(1)
Line Input #1, Line_FromFile
Line_Items = Split(Line_FromFile, ",")
Range("C"&row_num).Value = Line_Items(2)
Range("B"&row_num).Value = Line_Items(1)
Range("A"&row_num).Value = Line_Items(0)
row_num = row_num + 1
Loop
Close #1
```